# How to initialize array of cv::Mat with rows, cols and value?(In a c++ Class)

Tags: c++, initialization, opencv3.0

How to initialize an array with 10 Mat's?
I tried: (Its working in function but not in class)

```
cv::Mat outIm[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
  outIm[i] = Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
```

Is there something like below legal?

```
cv::Mat im[10](rows, cols, CV_8UC3);  //not working
```

Comment: Make a `std::array` and use the `fill` method, like this: `std::array<cv::Mat, 10> outIM; outIM.fill(cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0)))`.

Comment: Thanks @Mansoor. Your idea works well in a function, but still it does not work in a class(If I am not wrong). Is there no way to initialize in class. What do you think!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by **in a class**? If `outIM` were a member of a class, you could call `std::array::fill` inside the constructors? Or you could create a static member function which returns the initialized arrays, and use _default_ _initializers_ in your class.

Comment: Ah ok, I was not familiar with constructor. Let me explore that. Meanwhile If you can convert your comment to answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution:

```
class Foo
{
 // Function which returns a zero initialised cv::Mat
 static std:array<cv::Mat,10> MakeInitMatArray() {return {cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0))};}

 // In-class default-initializer
 std:array<cv::Mat,10> outIm = MakeInitMatArray();

 // ... rest of Foo class
};
```